# Why does factor analysis in Stata not restrict the to factors with eigenvalues greater than one when using maximum likelihood criterion?

Tags: stata, pca, factor-analysis

I am comparing two different methods for factor analysis in Stata: principal factors (as specified by the `pf` option) and maximum likelihood (as specified by the `ml` option). Here are the two commands I am comparing:

```
sysuse auto
factor price mpg headroom trunk weight length turn displacement gear_ratio, mineigen(1) pf
factor price mpg headroom trunk weight length turn displacement gear_ratio, mineigen(1) ml
```

I specify `mineigen(1)` to only keep factors with eigenvalues greater than unity. The factor loading matrix for `pf` retains one factor, as would be expected, given there is only one factor with eigenvalues greater than unity (eigenvalue = 5.8). **Why does the factor loading matrix for `ml` retain five factors, when there are only two factors with eigenvalues greater than unity?**

I'm not sure if the answer might have something to do with the solution for `ml` being a Heywood case; the help-file for Heywood case doesn't mention anything about the factor loading matrix.

Here is the output:

```
. factor price mpg headroom trunk weight length turn displacement gear_ratio, mineigen(1) pf
(obs=74)

Factor analysis/correlation                      Number of obs    =         74
    Method: principal factors                    Retained factors =          1
    Rotation: (unrotated)                        Number of params =          9

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         Factor  |   Eigenvalue   Difference        Proportion   Cumulative
    -------------+------------------------------------------------------------
        Factor1  |      5.80299      5.27017            0.8901       0.8901
        Factor2  |      0.53283      0.23069            0.0817       0.9719
        Factor3  |      0.30214      0.11137            0.0463       1.0182
        Factor4  |      0.19077      0.19287            0.0293       1.0475
        Factor5  |     -0.00210      0.02635           -0.0003       1.0472
        Factor6  |     -0.02845      0.01025           -0.0044       1.0428
        Factor7  |     -0.03869      0.04112           -0.0059       1.0369
        Factor8  |     -0.07981      0.08074           -0.0122       1.0246
        Factor9  |     -0.16055            .           -0.0246       1.0000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LR test: independent vs. saturated:  chi2(36) =  673.52 Prob>chi2 = 0.0000

Factor loadings (pattern matrix) and unique variances

    ---------------------------------------
        Variable |  Factor1 |   Uniqueness 
    -------------+----------+--------------
           price |   0.4846 |      0.7652  
             mpg |  -0.8148 |      0.3362  
        headroom |   0.5524 |      0.6948  
           trunk |   0.7398 |      0.4527  
          weight |   0.9756 |      0.0483  
          length |   0.9546 |      0.0887  
            turn |   0.8605 |      0.2596  
    displacement |   0.9138 |      0.1649  
      gear_ratio |  -0.7831 |      0.3867  
    ---------------------------------------

. 
end of do-file

. do "C:\Users\NAE215\AppData\Local\Temp\1\STD4dc4_000000.tmp"

. factor price mpg headroom trunk weight length turn displacement gear_ratio, mineigen(1) ml
(obs=74)
number of factors adjusted to 5

<log omitted>

Factor analysis/correlation                      Number of obs    =         74
    Method: maximum likelihood                   Retained factors =          5
    Rotation: (unrotated)                        Number of params =         35
                                                 Schwarz's BIC    =    151.498
    Log likelihood = -.4278555                   (Akaike's) AIC   =    70.8557

    
Warning: Solution is a Heywood case; that is, invalid or boundary values of uniqueness.

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         Factor  |   Eigenvalue   Difference        Proportion   Cumulative
    -------------+------------------------------------------------------------
        Factor1  |      3.87317      1.84053            0.4924       0.4924
        Factor2  |      2.03264      1.18001            0.2584       0.7508
        Factor3  |      0.85263     -0.07200            0.1084       0.8592
        Factor4  |      0.92463      0.74196            0.1176       0.9768
        Factor5  |      0.18267            .            0.0232       1.0000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LR test: independent vs. saturated:  chi2(36) =  673.52 Prob>chi2 = 0.0000
    LR test:   5 factors vs. saturated:  chi2(1)  =    0.77 Prob>chi2 = 0.3793
    (tests formally not valid because a Heywood case was encountered)

Factor loadings (pattern matrix) and unique variances

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variable |  Factor1   Factor2   Factor3   Factor4   Factor5 |   Uniqueness 
    -------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------
           price |   0.3182    0.7650    0.5600   -0.0000   -0.0000 |      0.0000  
             mpg |  -0.5844   -0.4288    0.0811   -0.3382    0.1998 |      0.3137  
        headroom |   0.6619   -0.0440   -0.1115    0.1121    0.0975 |      0.5254  
           trunk |   1.0000   -0.0063    0.0018   -0.0000    0.0000 |      0.0000  
          weight |   0.6758    0.5263   -0.1410    0.4482   -0.1185 |      0.0316  
          length |   0.7292    0.3721   -0.1515    0.4769   -0.1867 |      0.0445  
            turn |   0.6037    0.3428   -0.2584    0.4783   -0.1577 |      0.1976  
    displacement |   0.6128    0.5804   -0.2571    0.3750    0.2438 |      0.0215  
      gear_ratio |  -0.5137   -0.6260    0.5868    0.0001    0.0000 |      0.0000  
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```